# Can't build iOS app with Mapbox

Tags: ios, xcode, build, mapbox

I do all steps from Mapbox integration tutorial (https://www.mapbox.com/install/), which BTW, doesn't work. Then I try to find some answers here. So, my problem is:

[image: main problem]

[image: project structure]

At this point I don't know why it's not working or what I am missing.

I try do new project step by step from Mapbox tutorial many times, it doesn't work. Xcode version is 8.1

Because of comment @jmkiley I did update MacOS and then Xcode and problem disappear. Maybe I did not notice the min. requirements

Comment: Could you confirm whether you are following this installation process: https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/ ? Also, which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: yes, exactly that, my xcode version is 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial (if I still see good) never writed, that you need to have specific version of Xcode. I think its support at least last version. I used Xcode version 9.+ but should work with now current version 10.+ too. Of course specific Xcode version need  specific macOS version.

Error above is not very useful for get what the real problem is.

I found [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941588/ios-mapbox-annotation-not-opening?rq=1), where autor use Xcode 8 but with macOS Siera so maybe is more important version of macOS than Xcode, but that is only hypotesis